# kotlin/java match a number in a string with a regular expression

Tags: java, regex, kotlin

For example, if I have these strings, is there any way I can get 123 of all these strings, or 777 or 888?

`https://www.example.com/any/123/` and

`https://www.example.com/any/777/123/` and

`https://www.example.com/any/777/123/888`

What I mean is how to match the first or second or the third last number in the string.

Comment: I don't think that's the answer I'm looking for. I want to get the penultimate nth number in the string, not just the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use capture groups to solve this as

```
val strList = listOf("https://www.example.com/any/777/123/888", "https://www.example.com/any/123/", "https://www.example.com/any/777/123/")
val intList = mutableListOf<Int>()
val regex = Regex("/?(\\d+)")

strList.forEach { str ->
    regex.findAll(str).forEach {
        intList.add(it.groupValues[1].toInt())
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the answer I was looking for! Thank you! Also I would like to ask how to find the learning material for the regular content? I seem to have trouble finding them in China.

Answer (score 0):

With **Java**, You can make use of the Pattern and Matcher class from the `java.util.regex` package.
e.g for your case above, you want to match integers - use **\d** *Predefined character class* to match digits.

```
String str = "https://www.example.com/any/777/123/";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher matcher  = pattern.matcher(str);

for(; matcher.find(); System.out.println(matcher.group()));
```

In the above you loop through the String finding matches, and printing each subsequent found match.

Comment: I don't think that's the answer I'm looking for. I want to get the penultimate nth number in the string, not just the number.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the digits all follow a slash and nothing intervenes,

```
(?<=/)\d+(?=/\d+){0}$  parses the last number
(?<=/)\d+(?=/\d+){1}$  parses the second to last number
(?<=/)\d+(?=/\d+){2}$  parses the third to last,
etc.
```